# Syntax error when calling attributes from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a file (`threenames.py`) with three attributes a, b, and c each assigned to a string as follows

```
a = 'New York'
b = 'Baltimore'
c = 'Phoenix'
Print (a, b, c)
```

and would like to call these using the python code as follows

```
python threenames.py however I get a syntax error as follows
>>> python threenames.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python threenames.py
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a, b, and c are not "attributes" ... the are variable names.  Also Print is not a Python keyword nor standard function ... I have to assume that you meant **print** (which is a statement in older Python versions and a built-in function in Python3, a distinction which is probably not relevant to you at that point).

As others have pointed out the >>> prompt means that you're inside of a Python interpreter session.  You could "import" your threenames.py and it would execute it; but you should exit to the shell and run the program from there.  The details of doing that depend on your OS.

Answer (score 3):

The `>>>` is the Python interactive interpreter's prompt. `python threenames.py` is not a valid Python statement which is why it is giving you an error.

You can exit the Python REPL loop by hitting `Ctrl`+`D` or by executing `exit()`.
You will then see you normal shell prompt (probably ending with `$`) and can execute `python threenames.py`.

You can also instead just `import threenames` within the Python shell as it will execute all the code in that file but beware: if you update the code in your `threenames.py` file simply importing it again won't reload the code.

---

I'm assuming that your print formatting comes from actually using Python 2 instead of 3 as your syntax suggests; use it as a statement instead and get rid of the tuple as so:

```
a = 'New York'
b = 'Baltimore'
c = 'Phoenix'
print a, b, c
```

Comment: @VK20 You can accept my answer by clicking the green check mark next to my post if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the Python interactive interpreter's `>>>` prompt, type `exit()` and press *Enter*. After that you get your shell prompt back, where you can type `python threenames.py` and then press *Enter* to run the program.

Comment: Thanks that helped however I would like the output with just the names of the cities with out the ' between the names how do I do that?

Comment: use python 3, put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file, or remove the parentheses on the last line